# Allowing creation/modification of virtual aliases using web.config

Tags: iis, web.config

I've been given a problem to fix, and I initially thought of .htaccess files, except for one thing, I quickly realized it's an IIS server.  Is it possible to allow a webmaster the ability to modify the virtual directories using web.config files in the same way you can using .htaccess files?  If so, any ideas on where I can find details on how this is done that I can communicate with the end client?   We want to be able to do this without having to provide access to the IIS console to the webmaster.

An example of the desired change is:

http://FQDN/Careers/Careers.aspx?locale=en-ca&uid=Careers

have http:FQDN/careers point to the above, but modified/added/removed by the end user using web.config

Answer (score 0):

IIS doesn't support delegated management of virtual directories, but [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool) is an option if you have admin rights to the server and want to set IIS so that users can mark folders as applications and recycle, stop and start app pools.  The end user can do it using IIS Manager.

However, if what you really need is redirecting URLs, that can be done with [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite) which is managed with web.config.  It needs to be installed on the server (reboot required) and then web.config gives full flexibility in customizing URLs.